# Which template engine for Node.js has best performance when being using in server side?

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

I want to use Pug in server side as Node.js template engine for my websites, by I afraid worry performance. When we use Pug locally just as HTML pre-processor, performance is not critical, but if Pug compilation makes server response time longer, I forced to select other template engine.

I suppose, as far as template engine is close to HTML it has better performance but worse maintainability than Pug (if it's wrong please correct me).

Comment: On a sidenote, Pug performance would improve when you set node env to production. It uses cache in production mode instead of performing file reads for each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pug is a good choice.

> I suppose, as far as template engine is close to HTML it has better performance but worse maintainability than Pug (if it's wrong please correct me).

Actually the performance are moreover bound to the *quality* of the template engine. If you take a template engine which starts to something quite similar to HTML but written by dogs, probably it has worst performance than pug.

With pug you can also *cache* the template functions to save some CPU time in exchange of some memory...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am glad about has been recommended to use Pug is server side.